# Solution to Inequality: $2y(1+x)(1+xt)-(t-1)(y^2-z^2)>0$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I'm studying conditions under which the inequality
$$2y(1+x)(1+xt)-(t-1)(y^2-z^2)>0$$
holds.
The restrictions on the variables are $x>0$, $t>1$, $y>0$ and $y>z>-y$.

WolframAlpha suggests that one solution is
$$y<\frac{2(1+x)(1+xt)}{t-1}.$$

However, when I try to show this, I end up at the inequality
$$y<\frac{z^2}{y}+\frac{2(1+x)(1+xt)}{t-1}.$$
At this point I am unsure how to "get rid of" the term involving $z$. Any help or tips would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $y > 0$, I think you can get $$ y < \frac{2(1+x)(1+xt)}{t-1} =: a$$ when bounding $\frac{z^2}{y}$ from below by $0$. Hence, if $y < a$, then $ y < \frac{z^2}{y} + a$ and thus the original inequality holds.

Comment: Let me try and rephrase so that I can check my understanding: because $(z^2/y)\in[0, y)$, $y<a$ holds at its lowest point $(z^2/y)=0$. Therefore, it will also hold when we add something positive to $a$ as well.

Comment: Yes. You want that the bound holds for all $z$. Hence, it must hold for the $z$ that minimizes the bound, i.e. $z^* = \text{argmin}_z z^2/y + a$ (which you know will hold). Since $y > 0$ and because $a$ is independent of $z$, the optimum is obtained for $z^* = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Most appreciated.